# Swift Array Filtering

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filtering

I have a `Game Class` with property `id: String` and im trying to filter the array `gamesArray: [Game]` based on ids contained in another array `haveGameArray: [String]` and return the results on `gamesFilteredArray: [Game]`

```
// Filter the array by the contained in self.haveGameArray
self.gamesFilteredArray = self.gamesArray.filter(
{
     (game: Game) -> Bool in

     let id = game.id

     return self.haveGameArray.contains(id)
})
```

Its not working and i don't know what to do, because the logic its right

Comment: The code is working =)
`self.haveGameArray` was empty in my tests

Comment: If you are looking for a simple perfect example of Array filter in Swift2, this is it.